# Unable to print result using decorators

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-decorators

I am new to learning python and i faced a weared problem using decorator. I am unable to print result from @decorate1.Will really appreciate if you can help me with the problem. Please find the code below:

```
def decorate1(function):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print("the arguments are ",args)
    return wrapper


def fileoperation(function):
    def wrapper():
        f=function()
        with open("sample.txt",'w') as wf:
            wf.write(f)
    return wrapper


def listoperation(function):
    def wrapper(*args):
      mylst=[]
      for i in args:
        mylst.append(i)
      print(mylst)
    return wrapper




@listoperation
@decorate1
def display(name,age):
    pass

display('vijay',31)

@fileoperation
def filestring():
    return "This is a file"


filestring()


Output:
['vijay', 31]
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Comment: missing @ before decorate1

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your decorator is not returning the wrapped function.

I'll make an example, excluding the `filestring()` function since it's the same error.

```
def decorate1(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("the arguments are ",args)
        function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def listoperation(function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      mylst=[]
      for i in args:
        mylst.append(i)
      print(mylst)
      function(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@listoperation
@decorate1
def display(name,age):
    pass

display('vijay',31)
```

As you can see, some points have changed in your functions:

- Even if not needed for the example, it's safer to always build your wrapper accepting and forwarding `*args, **kwargs`, so any argument in any form passed will be forwarded to the wrapped function
- The wrapper should call the wrapped function, with all his parameters: otherwise the 'wrapped' function won't be executed!

---

**GENERAL EXAMPLE:**

Sometimes, an example can help to 'wrap' your mind around the decorators.

Let's say you want a function that prints the first `N` natural numbers:

```
def my_numbers(N):
    return list(range(N))
```

Then you notice that this function, along with many others, is sometime failing. You have the suspect that someone is passing arguments that you do not expect, so you want to print which argument is being passed and the output of the function, without interfering in the function.
You write a decorator, but since all the functions take a different number of arguments and key-value arguments, you keep it general:

```
def my_logger(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Someone has passed these arguments: {0}".format(*args))
        res = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print("With the values that someone passed, I got the following output: {0}".format(res))
        return res
    return wrapper
```

And after decorating our function:

```
@my_logger
def my_numbers(N):
    return list(range(N))
```

We get the following output:

> Someone has passed these arguments: 4
>   With the values that someone passed, I got the following output: [0, 1, 2, 3]
>   [0, 1, 2, 3]